# Snowflake row level security and data masking from service account

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-api, okta

I have done data masking and row level security based on the role of the user in snowflake. Now we are Integrating Tableau and Looker with snowflake using service account for these tools. Now since it is going to be a service account, which all the user will have access to. I am wondering how can we implement the masking and row level security.

Please note the access to snowflake is using SSO which is done by OKTA.

I am not very familiar with Tableau or Looker So wondering If we can do these security features from these tool or will have to bring in OKTA configuration(somehow) to configure this.

One way I am thinking to control this is by having multiple Service Account for the tool and depending on account assigned the role.

Or if people here can help me for how to implement this with a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake has partnered with Tableau and Looker to integrate the access to Snowflake using OAuth.

Please refer to this document on how to set up the integration.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-partner.html

The user will log in to Snowflake using their own account via Tableau or Looker and all the data masking and row-level security that was applied to the user's role will take effect.

Comment: yes that can be done.. but our company is more interested in using service account for tableau which mean it will be same Tableau_user for all the users.. I think in that case the row level security or masking wont worked.. as u said will have to use individual user id to access snowflake from tableau

Comment: Well, in that case, I would think that all the users will log in to Tableau as Tableau_user and grant Tableau_user to the role that you applied the row-level security or masking.